# Iterar día por día

Tags: c#, bucle-for

Estoy tratando de iterar en un rango de fechas, me sale todo correcto si ingreso de un mes abajo al actual:

Ejemplo del 1-08-2022 al 14-09-2022, para ese uso el código siguiente:

```
    DateTime Fecini = new DateTime(2022, 8, 1);
    DateTime FecFinal = new DateTime(2022, 9, 14);
    System.TimeSpan dif = FecFinal - Fecini;
    DateTime FecSec;//fecha seleccionad en el bucle
    for (int n = 0; n <=dif.Days; n++)
    {
        FecSec = Fecini.AddDays(n);
        Console.WriteLine(FecSec);
    }
```

Me imprime correctamente, pero yo lo que quiero es que sea del dia de hoy al mes pasado(14-09-2022 al 01-08-2022), uso el siguiente código pero el problema es que no se detiene en el 1ro del mes de agosto, se sigue y sigue imprimiendo mas fechas.

Espero me puedan apoyar con ello o apoyarme donde es mi error para corregirlo.

```
        DateTime Fecini = new DateTime(2022, 9, 14);
        DateTime FecFinal = new DateTime(2022, 8, 1);
        System.TimeSpan dif = Fecini - FecFinal;
        DateTime FecSec;
        for (int n = 0; n <= dif.Days; n--)
        {
            FecSec = Fecini.AddDays(n);
            Console.WriteLine(FecSec);
        }
```

Comment: En qué orden quieres que se imprima empezando desde agosto a septiembre, o desde septiembre a agosto?

Comment: Al igual que pregunta @Yussef, confirma el orden.
Pero el bucle lo tiene <=, siempre va a ser menor porque estás disminuyendo con n--.

Comment: El orden que yo quisiera que tomara es de septiembre hacia agosto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay veces que se olvida que un for puede iterar sobre otros elementos distintos a un entero. A mí me parece más legible hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
DateTime Fecini = new DateTime(2022, 8, 1);
DateTime FecFinal = new DateTime(2022, 9, 14);

for (DateTime f = Fecini ; f <= FecFinal ; f = f.AddDays(1))
{
   Console.WriteLine(f.ToString());
}
```

En orden inverso:

```
for (DateTime f = FecFinal; f >= Fecini; f = f.AddDays(-1))
{
   Console.WriteLine(f.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Yussef, también funciono de maravilla las dos opciones y reduces código.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así:

Te estaba contando negativos, por eso nunca se cumplía la condición `n <= dif.Days` y `n` siempre iba a ser menor

```
    for (int n = 0; n <= dif.Days; n++)//Aquí se incrementa la n
    {
        FecSec = Fecini.AddDays(-n);// y aquí se decrementa n
        Console.WriteLine(FecSec);
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias valle50, me funciono perfectamente.